# When is necessary integrate Apache httpd with apache tomcat (mod_jk)?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, httpd, mod-jk

Apache sites, recommend the integration of httpd and tomcat(mod_jk). The first for static and the second for dynamic content. What about the case that the entire page is dynamic. Does it still make sense to integrate both servers? What would be the advantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It allows you to use the other features of HTTPd (e.g. rewriting via mod_rewrite).
2. It allows you to run Tomcat as non-root, preventing privilege violations.

Comment: There is no requirement to run Tomcat as root, so #2 is not really a good reason to use Apache httpd.

Comment: Other good reasons to use httpd/mod_jk:

1. load-balancing across multiple Tomcat backends
2. deploying webapps to different Tomcats/JVMs and still accessing them from the same port
3. offering a heterogeneous service environment: Tomcat for some webapps, PHP/Perl/CGI for others, since httpd is better for those